# Loops to receive the minimum based on user iput - no arrays

Tags: java, while-loop, variable-assignment, minimum

I have attempted to create a loop that asks for user input (unlimited numbers) once I press 0 it will take the lowest number to give me the minimum. I though it worked but I tested with negative numbers and it does not give me the negative number as the minimum it keeps giving me the 0 as the minimum. Any suggestions.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

int num = scan.nextInt();
int min;

while (num != 0)
{
    num = min = scan.nextInt();

    if( num < min )
    {
        min = num;
    }

    if (num == 0)
    {
        System.out.print(min);
    }
}
scan.close();
```

Comment: What do you think this statement does?  `num = min = scan.nextInt();`  After this statement, when will `num < min` be true?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're always overwriting your value of min:

`num = min = scan.nextInt();`

is identical in function to:

`min = scan.nextInt();
num = min;`

If you remove the `min` part of that statement, it should work just fine:

`num = scan.nextInt();`